# How to count a field which has the most record in the gridview and display them in a label?

Tags: c#, gridview, count, record, outer-join

I have two tables which is doctor and medicalhistory which have relationship with each other. I use outer join to display the doctorname in doctor table instead of the doctorID. Now what I want is to display the Doctor name which have the most record in a label. See the first image, since Jack have 3 record and John only have 1 record, I would like to display Jack in the label. So the output will be GP: Jack. The label name is called lblGP. Any more help other than RadioSpace method which i duno how to write the dataset. help???

[image]

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;


public partial class member_viewmedicalhistory : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            // call BindGridView
            bindGridView();

        }
    }

    private void bindGridView()
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"].ToString());
        //get connection string from web.config
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        string strCommandText = "SELECT convert(varchar, mCheckupDate, 103) AS CheckUpDate, mReview AS Review, pat.pFirstName AS FirstName, doc.dFirstName as Doctor, ill.illnessType  from medicalhistory AS hist ";
        strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN PATIENT as pat on hist.patientid = pat.patientid ";
        strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCTOR as doc on hist.doctorid = doc.doctorid ";
        strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN ILLNESS as ill on hist.illnessid = ill.illnessid ";
        strCommandText += " WHERE hist.patientid = " + ID.ToString();

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

            myConnect.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            GrdViewMedicalHistory.DataSource = dt;
            GrdViewMedicalHistory.DataBind();
            lblResult.Text = "";

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "Error:" + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnect.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well my first suggestion is to use

```
    string strCommandText = @"SELECT convert(varchar, mCheckupDate, 103) AS CheckUpDate, mReview 
    AS Review, pat.pFirstName AS FirstName, doc.dFirstName as Doctor, ill.illnessType  from    
    medicalhistory AS hist 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PATIENT as pat on hist.patientid = pat.patientid 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCTOR as doc on hist.doctorid = doc.doctorid 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ILLNESS as ill on hist.illnessid = ill.illnessid 
     WHERE hist.patientid = " + ID.ToString();
```

second just use a second datareader and datatable and write a query to return what you are looking for then plug that into your label

or shortcut you could be to use LINQ `dT.Select()....First();//return string` type code

article on untyped datasets and linq: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399399(v=vs.110).aspx

oh and it looks like your using VS you should be able automatically generate a typed dataset. Which will make things a lot easier.